# How to setup MS SQL Server with multiple web server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webserver

Right now my web application is using single domain like abc.com in future we will be adding sub domain (different IP) to redirect some users(to reduce overload on main domain). So the problem is our application which allows user to login, send message to other user which will appear on their homepage (the page they land after sign in) and their are some other critical resource which can be edit by group of people at same time (like Resource Calender). So it's very important to check that user's are not working on old or changed data and there is no two different version of same resource calender(if two sql server are used). as am new to this type of problem can any one know of any systematic approach to solve this problem or some tutorial link on this topic would be great. thankyou.

Comment: The answer is simple: don't use two SQL Servers serving the same database.

Comment: That was just an assumption. but the question is if two web application are host on two different servers then how to connect them to sql server which is host on only one of the servers.

Comment: Just use a connection string that points to whichever server is running SQL Server. Ideally, it would be a server which is _not_ running IIS, and which is _not_ located in the DMZ.